# Can I edit the title of a job in Facebook?

Tags: facebook

I have a job listing with several projects under it, but it is listed under the wrong name (apparently, this place is also a school in Illinois, whereas I work on the east coast).  Is there any way to edit the title of the listing without recreating the entire thing?